# What is GCC/Clang equivalent of -fp-model fast=1 in ICC

Tags: gcc, floating-point, clang, icc, fast-math

As I read on [Intel's website](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/the-default-icc-behavior-favors-speed-over-ieee-floating-point-compliance):

> Intel compiler uses /fp-model fast=1 as defaults. This optimization
>   favors speed over standards compliance. You may use compiler option
>   -mieee-fp to get compliant code.

My understanding of the [fp-model](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/525039) option in ICC is that (correct me if I'm wrong):

- `precise` corresponds to default settings in GCC and Clang,
- `fast=2` is similar to `-ffast-math`,
- `fast=1` is somewhere between.

What options in GCC or Clang would make floating point math most similar to Intel's default `-fp-model fast=1`?

Answer (score 3):

As it follows from GCC's set_fast_math_flags function, `ffast-math` option (at least in GCC 5.2) is equivalent to

(1) unsafe opts group:

```
-fno-trapping-math
-fassociative_math
-fno-signed-zeros
-freciprocal-math
```

(2) other guys:

```
-ffinite-math-only
-fno-errno-math
-fno-signaling-nans
-fno-rounding-math
-fcx-limited-range
```

First group is abbreviated with the option `-funsafe-math-optimizations`.

You should figure out what comes in ICC and try to combine those flags to make desired effect.

Comment: well, it doesn't answer the question (which is about `-fp-model fast=1` not `-ffast-math`)

Comment: I don't know in which exact way fp-model fast=1 violates IEEE. I just explained what options together constitutes ffast-math in gcc, so that you can play around with those 9 guys, looking for whatever you want in-between.